# DataTables - Setting language

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to use datatables using Spanish as language.

I currently use this, following documentation to turn html table into a DataTables:

```
$('#product_table').DataTable( {
...
} );
```

However, while checking the official DataTables documentation, I see that `.dataTable` is used instead of `.DataTables`.

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
        "language": {
            "url": "dataTables.german.lang"
        }
 } );
```

How can I define the language using the first form `.DataTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer This link your answer is here.

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/language.html

for More Link.

[enter link description here](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/)

Comment: The second link actually is confusing as it uses a different API (I guess it is old one?), I used first one with the extended info included here https://datatables.net/reference/option/language

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
$('#product_table').DataTable( {
   language: {
    url: 'http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json'
   }
} );
```